# Apache Royale : addEventListener / removeEventListener best practice

Tags: addeventlistener, apache-royale

In Flex, the best practice when using a `addEventListener` was to call `removeEventListener` to avoid memory leak and/or event to be called twice if component could be created many times (like popups)

So `addEventListener` was mainly used in `addedToStage` event function and `removeEventListener` was in `removedFromStage` event function

**What is the best practice for Apache Royale ?**

It seem that `addEventListener` should be in a `initComplete` event. But as Apache Royale component life cycle is not very clear for me, does I need to take care of calling `removeEventListener`, and if yes when (with a specific event ?) ?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

I think the same applies like in Flex. But you just should be care of remove listeners when you create components and can be removed eventually. Like in Flex if the object instance will be created just one time and is permanent through the session, you don't need to worry about it.